# Multithreading in C, get the average of 4 arrays

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm new to multithreading had my first lesson yesterday. So I've wrote a program to get the average of 4 big arrays , each array is a thread and the main waits for all the threads and gives the average of the 4 arrays. This is possible because each thread gives the average of one array. The array is just a headerfile with a float array.

It compiles but gives me a segmentation error and I don't see why.

```
    #include "gemiddelde.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float *gemiddelde(void *arg)
{
    float *a;
    int i;
    a = (float *)arg;
    float  * som;

    for( i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
       *som += a[i];
    *som = *som / 100000;
    return som;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2,t3,t4;
    float  * som1, * som2, * som3, * som4, *result;

    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,gemiddelde,a1);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,gemiddelde,a2);
    pthread_create(&t3,NULL,gemiddelde,a3);
    pthread_create(&t4,NULL,gemiddelde,a4);

    pthread_join(t1,som1);
    pthread_join(t2,som2);
    pthread_join(t3,som3);
    pthread_join(t4,som4);

    usleep(1);
    *result = *som1 + *som2 + *som3 + *som4;
    printf("Gemiddelde is: %f ", *result);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Kind regards,

Comment: Yout somX are all pointers and no memory is assigned to them. Same goes for result. Use som1 = new float;

Comment: Compile with debug information using `gcc -g gemiddelde.c`, then attach the debugger `gdb ./a.out`, `run`. The debugger breaks on the segmentation fault and you can see on which line the error occurs.

Comment: Where's the initialization of a1..a4?

Comment: @Shadow: `new` is not an operator in C

Comment: Generally, I would strongly suggest to get comfortable with how pointers and allocation work in C, _before_ moving on to more advanced topics like multi-threading.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
*result = *som1 + *som2 + *som3 + *som4;
```

`result` is used unitialized. Make it a plain `float` instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

From your current code, segfault occurs because `som*` aren't initialized -- they are [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: Thanks, got it ;-) didn't create the pointer with new. Thanks guys.

Comment: @user1007522: `new` is a C++ construct. Apart from that, there's absolutely no need for dynamic allocation in this program.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very problematic, because the thread code requires memory to store the result, and as it stands your code is plain wrong because it doesn't have *any* memory and just dereferences a dangling pointer. But even allocating memory inside the thread is not a great idea, because it's not clear who is responsible for it and who will clean it up. So it's much better to allocate *all* your required memory in the main function. First some boiler plate to set up the thread argument data:

```
 typedef struct thread_arg_type_
 {
     float * data;
     size_t  len;
     float   retval;
 } thread_arg_type;

 thread_arg_type * create_thread_arg(size_t n)
 {
     thread_arg_type * result = malloc(sizeof(thread_arg_type));
     if (!result) return NULL;

     float * const p = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
     if (!p)
     {
         free(result);
         return NULL;
     }

     result->len = n;
     result->data = p;
     return result;
 }

 void free_thread_arg(thred_arg_type * r)
 {
     if (r) free(r->data);
     free(r);
 }
```

Now here's how we use it:

```
 int main()
 {
     thread_arg_type * arg;
     pthread_t t;

     arg = create_thread_arg(array1_size);
     pthread_create(&t, NULL, getmiddle, arg);

     // ...

     pthread_join(t, NULL);
     printf("The result is: %f.\n", arg->retval);
     free_thread_arg(arg);
 }
```

And finally we must adapt `getmiddle`:

```
void * getmiddle(thread_arg_t * arg)
{
    arg->retval = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i != arg->len; ++i)
        arg->retval += arg->data[i];

    arg->retval /= arg->len;

    return NULL;
}
```